# Failed elections x 2. Why didn't people want to stand?

Tags: discussion, election, moderation, moderators

The site has now had its second failed election ([I](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318/2020-community-moderator-election-failed-election), [II](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324/2021-community-moderator-election-failed-election)), with no candidates putting their hat in the ring to become a site moderator. The actual activity for mods seems pretty low (less than [1 action per day](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320/2020-a-year-in-moderation) at present), so the position shouldn't be too onerous or difficult.

Jnat says that "*the next steps are for the Community to consider here what may have gone wrong*" and that the CMs will be working with the moderation "team" (which currently consists of just [one individual](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users/75/canadian-luke)) to offer their help and support moving forward.

**So, what did go wrong and why were individuals unwilling to stand?**

Answer (score 4):

One can help the site with no Moderator's hat.

I, for one, see my role as helping the Mods with cleaning low-quality content. One excellent instrument for that is [Review Queues](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/review).

Even more, Moderators have the privilege of binding vote; in other words, they always act single-handedly on posts — which is not exactly what I want for myself.

If you really want help the site, here's the (obvious) todo list:

- visit the site on a regular basis;
- vote; the reputation is the "currency" of the Stack Exchange network;
- visit Review Queues;
- flag bad posts.

Naturally, you would need some reputation gained to get access to necessary instruments.

Comment: The immediate worry is that with only a single moderator (who by their own admission is feeling "burnt out") and no-one willing to take on some of the workload, the site is at severe risk of being closed.

Comment: Yea, I need a break... Or at least a helping hand.

Comment: @bytebuster so the reason you don't want to be a mod is because you don't want your close votes and reopen votes to be "binding" ?

Comment: @NikeDattani - Which seems a little counter-productive if the entire site is in danger of being yanked.

Comment: @Valorum you're preaching to the choir :)